# How to search for lines matching current line in vim

Tags: command-line, search, highlight, delimiter-matching, mark

I usually search for words by `:/string`, but if I have to search entire current line, how to do that.

```
event: 1  beacon: 0x02              //line 1
event: 19 beacon: 0x02              //line 2
event: 1  beacon: 0x03              //line 3
event: 1  beacon: 0x02              //line 4
event: 8  beacon: 0x01              //line 5
event: 19 beacon: 0x02              //line 6
event: 1  beacon: 0x02              //line 7
```

For example, if `cursor` is presently at `line 1` how to search similarly as `:/` for text containing entire current line. The cursor should jump then to matching `line 4`, and again to `line 7`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Yank the line (into the unnamed register), without including the newline at the end: `0y$`
2. Initiate a *very nomagic* search: `/\V`
3. Add the yanked line: `<c-r>"`
4. Fire off the search: `<cr>`

As [@EvergreenTree points out in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6208/how-to-search-for-lines-matching-current-line-in-vim/6210?noredirect=1#comment9636_6210), you can of course create a mapping to perform all the steps in one go:

```
nnoremap <leader>* 0y$/\V<c-r>"<cr>
```

Relevant help topics:

```
:help registers
:help /magic
:help c_CTRL-R
```

N.B. If the line you're searching for contains backslashes, you'll still need to go through and escape them (by adding another backslash), even with a *very nomagic* search.

Comment: Of course, you could also create a mapping for this:  `nnoremap {key} 0y$/\V<c-r>"<cr>`

Comment: why very no magic?

Comment: @CervEd Because you want to match character-for-character against what's in the line, not use it as a regular expression where special characters are treated differently.

Answer (score 12):

Especially for mapping purposes, I find using `getline()` more elegant than doing the yanking yourself. Calling `getline()` with a string `'.'` returns the line under the cursor. There are two good options for using this:

```
:exec '/' . getline('.')
```

which parses the strings `'/'` and what is returned from `getline()` together and executes that as a vim command.

or

```
/<C-r>=getline('.')<CR>
```

which uses the expression register `@=`. The expression following `=` is evaluated after the first `<CR>` and placed in the command line.

Comment: Nice! When the line contains character like `/` or `'` it does not work very well. Anyway, I learn something today! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers all fail if your line contains certain items that are interpreted as a part of a pattern. The `\V` point gets most of the way there but still messes up with the backslash.

Try this to escape the backslashes...

```
/\V<C-R>=escape(getline('.'), '\')
```

And then if you're using it in a mapping you'll need one or two `<Enter>`s at the end depending on how you want it to work.

Comment: Excellent answer! Lines often contain both kinds of slash which confuse the other answers. That last argument of _escape_ should include a forward slash too though: `escape(…, '/\')`

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would get a [visual star](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search) plugin ([there are few out there](http://vimawesome.com/?q=star)). There is a nice Vimcast about this: [Search for the selected text](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-for-the-selected-text/). This means you can select the line visually and then press `*`.

If a plugin isn't your thing you can add the following mapping to your `vimrc`:

```
xnoremap * :<c-u>let @/=@"<cr>gvy:let [@/,@"]=[@",@/]<cr>/\V<c-r>=substitute(escape(@/,'/\'),'\n','\\n','g')<cr><cr>
```

Note: Visual-block (`<c-v>`) is not supported for this mapping.

Comment: I added the mappings but actually it's jumping to the first matching word and NOT selecting the entire line.

Comment: If it is match a word then I assume you are using `*` from normal mode or do not have the mapping installed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

With [vim-asterisk](https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-asterisk) installed just use `V$*` (or `0v$*`) to select the current line and search for it.

In the second command `0` is not necessary if the cursor is already on the start of the line.

Comment: Doesn't `*` only search for the word under the cursor, and not the current visual selection?

Comment: @EvergreenTree I did forget to mention the plugin. Thanks for notice

Answer (score 2):

One more way to do this is using the command-line window: `yy/<Ctrl-F>p<Enter>`

- Yank the whole line you need with `yy`
- Press `/` and then Ctrl-F to open command-line window
- Press `p` to paste the line
- Press Enter to start the search

Comment: You can also use `q/` to get the same effect as `/<c-f>`

Answer (score 2):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Searching_for_expressions_which_include_slashes points out that the search register can be set directly, like this:

```
:let @/='/abc/def/ghi/'
```

This allows search on the line and works even when the line includes slashes.

So to make, say, `\*` map to a line search:

```
nnoremap <leader>* :set hlsearch<cr>:let @/=getline('.')<cr>
```